# Installed ubuntu on netbook but unity is too heavy, would i benefit from installing mir?

Tags: unity, 13.10, laptop, mir

I'm running on an atom netbook with 2gb ram. But the machines runs a lot cooler under win7 than under ubuntu. My first thought was because of unity putting to much load on the machine.
After searching high and low yesterday, i came across mir, apparently that's the next thing for ubuntu.

Would i benefit by installing it?
How would i install it?
I know it's still in development, but would i be fine with a machine that's only used for school aka internet, mail & word processing?

Comment: You'd probably be better off installing something a little more lightweight, like XFCE, LXDE or MATE instead. You have a whole array of options when it comes to lighter desktop environments, and they'll be a lot more stable than replacing X11 completely.

Comment: And Mir isn't stable yet, still in development.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. Not sure, but could an older version of ubuntu with unity 2d be recommended, compared to xfce ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Don't do it.

Mir is a display server and it's used just for displaying stuff. Just like Wayland or X. (Yes, your system is using X right now.) "Hey, X! Stuff on the screen has changed. Could you please redraw it?"

On the other hand Unity is a desktop environment and it's responsible for the bar you see on top of the screen, the dock and menu you use to launch apps, etc. "Hey, Unity! User has clicked the menu button! Please make the image of an open menu, so X can draw it on the screen."

Mir is supposed to be more efficient than X, but the version of Unity you use is not prepared for Mir. It would be specially treated. (Mir would pretend that it's the X.) That special treating would make everything slower than using X directly. And Mir is in development and that means bugs. You don't want bugs, trust me.

As for running hot... We're not wizards and we need more info about your netbook. Without it I can only guess. Perhaps the processor usage is high? (Check it in System Monitor app.) Or maybe your graphics drivers are not making optimal use of your graphic card? (What graphic card and drivers do you use?)

So what is your version of Ubuntu, what netbook model is it exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. As to my netbook, it's a packard bell dot se: dot_se-333nc. Atom n450, GMA 3150. As to system monitor it looks like thunderbird requires 30/40% and system monitor itself also takes up 30/40%. I haven't installed any additional drivers.

Comment: Oh, right Atom netbooks use Intel GPUs. That means you have appropriate Intel drivers, they are included in Ubuntu. Constant 30/40% CPU usage sounds high, that might be one of the problems. You can try using another desktop environment, but I'm not sure how much it will change. Oh, you can install powertop. It's a command-line tool (and thus a bit awkward to use) that can show you what's eating your battery power. I guess it's the same thing that makes your netbook go hot. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask, but I'm not an expert. I run my laptop in a stock configuration.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the system itself takes up a lot of cpu time, but the programs. I also use thunderbird on win7 and there it does not use that much cpu time to just sit in the dock. But the interface seems a bit sluggish and the cpu fan is constantly running when on battery. So i was thinking that it was the gpu that was being loaded to much but i don't know how to check for that.

Comment: Well, that might be GPU, but I don't know how to check for that too. Sluggishness and running hot may suggest that CPU is used for graphics acceleration (via LLVMpipe), but CPU usage is low and graphic drivers are installed, so that's not it. Let's sit and wait for someone more clever than me :)